# Send event only once per session?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

Is it possible to send a google analytics event only once per session? I don't want to send my specific event with every pageview.

What I want to achieve:

I'm running a website without any ads at the moment. And I want to test how many visitors of my website are using adblockers.

I would add an element like

```
<div class="ad"></div>
```

which would be filtered out by probably every adblocker (at least most of them). Then I just would test with jquery if the element exists

```
$(function(){
     function test(){
         var len = $('.ad').length;
         if(len === 0){
             ga.send(..);
         }
     }

    // give adblockers a sec to remove everything, just in case
    setTimeout(test,500);

});
```

---

I could probably use a workaround with a custom cookie, like

```
// simplified
if (!cookie) {
    test();
}
```

But I'd be interested if this is possible with google api only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics events are a hit type (like pageviews) which can not be scoped to sessions or users. Even if you could only send one event per session (using either cookies or sessionStorage, you wouldn't actually get the whole picture in your GA reports.

To offer a better solution, consider using a Custom Dimension with a scope of "session" to store that data. What's cool about this is that the dimension is applied to **all** hit types within the scope- meaning any pageview, event, etc. also has the dimension associated with it.

To do this, create the dimension in Google Analytics Admin under the Property settings within Custom Definitions. Get the index number (a string that looks like `'dimension1'` or `'dimension 4'`) and paste the line **BEFORE** sending the pageview (ideally) or an event.

**Remember:** Dimensions are not hits, so simply setting them does nothing until a hit is also sent! Also, be sure to enable [non-interaction](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#non-interaction_events) on the events (if that is the route you choose) or else you will be misreporting bounces from those using Ad Blockers.

Here is the ideal snippet (Note: if you are going to setTimeout as part of your detection, do not use this method as it would delay the pageview send too... *Consider a method that doesn't need a timeout.*):

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

//Detection goes here. If true:
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Ad Blocker'); //Change 'dimension1' to yours.

ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Your code from above would look like this if you can't do the detection before the `<head>` GA send pageview snippet.

```
function test(){
     var len = $('.ad').length;
     if(len === 0){
         ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Ad Blocker'); //Change 'dimension1' to yours.
         ga('send', 'event', 'Ad Blocker', {nonInteraction: true}); //Add action and label as needed.
     }
 }
```