# Google Analytics Event Unique Per Session

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a site where I track click outs, one user may click out several times so if I have 100 users I may have 300 click out events. This is ok for a rough guide but ideally I would like to know how many users have clicked out so 100 users 85 users clicked out.

I could write some js on my site to handle this store in a cookie but I was wondering if there is anything in ga.js that will allow me to fire an event once per session.

Comment: This seems the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376275/send-event-only-once-per-session with the same (maybe somewhat more elaborate) completely workable solution.

Comment: Why not use a segment where session contains an event of the type you want, and report Sessions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom Dimensions to scope things to the session (or even the user). Create a dimension in the Google Analytics admin tab under Property within Custom Definitions.

Set the scope to session, then copy the `ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Description Here');` and paste it **before** sending the event (obviously, change "Description Here" to your own explanation. Also, make sure `'dimension1'` matches the index it gives you.

Custom dimensions (and metrics) are tied to hit types, so simply setting them does nothing until a hit type is sent- so either a pageview or an event.

Once you've created the dimension, you can use it for anything you would a standard dimension in reporting- including segments and custom reports.

Hope that helps!

Comment: so the usual GA event (category, action, label) combination is a hit type of event?

Comment: That's correct. The four hit types are "pageview", "event", "timing", and "exception".